# Android notification icon won't appear and is always a square/circle

Tags: react-native, android-notifications, react-native-firebase

I have two types of notification in my application. I have a `foreground` service which populates the notification bar for when the geolocation of the application is enabled and posting to an API.

The second type is a cloud messaging firebase notification that is triggered from the console for now, but will eventually be triggered from a backend server posting to the firebase cloud messaging API.

The `foreground` service seems to use my application's launcher Icon, regardless of what I do, and the FCM notification uses the default android notification icon (a small android logo in a circle).

However, they are both colored using the API to change the accent on them.

In both situations I am trying to use a `drawable/ic_stat_home` where `ic_stat_home` is an image, with a transparent background and an alpha/white icon of a house (generated from https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ and extracted to the res folder)

Here is my manifest (which only applies to the FCM part of the question)

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_home" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
    android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
```

Is there something wrong with my icon or my implementation?
Edit: `FirebaseMessaging: Icon with id: 2130903040 uses an invalid gradient. Using fallback icon.` Is the error i see in Logcat. However when I open the image it is entirely white with only transparancy, what am I missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. no update on this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ever since the android upgraded to lolipop the small icon on the notification comes in black and white only...
you need to make sure that your icon has a transparent background, i.e. the icon's shape should be the only thing available.
As it will be available in only one color, it would be best to give your icon a single color.
Suppose your icon is a circle the it should not have anything i  the middle.

eg:-
[image: Gmail Icon] [image: Gmail Notification]
the image does not have anything in middle of the circle, just the shape of the circle...
this is called transparent background
but it can be changed with the `.setColor()` method as shown in the code below.

Here's the code to set the color of the notification icon:-

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appypie_small);
    notificationBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notification_color));
} 
else {
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appypie_small);
}
```